# Getting "code challenge does not match previously saved code verifier" error on supabase github auth

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-js

I was trying to make github auth work on an next.js application with supabase, everything seems to work but when the user is redirected back from github to the site, the site encounters an supabase error.

Here's the auth handler and the error for reference.

```
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const code = requestUrl.searchParams.get('code')

  if (code) {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies })
    await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code)
  }

  // URL to redirect to after sign in process completes
  return NextResponse.redirect(requestUrl.origin)
}
```

```
- error AuthApiError: code challenge does not match previously saved code verifier
    at handleError (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/950.js:3541:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async _handleRequest (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/950.js:3589:9)
    at async _request (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/950.js:3568:18)
    at async SupabaseAuthClient._exchangeCodeForSession (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/950.js:1620:33)
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/950.js:2027:28 {
  __isAuthError: true,
  status: 403
}
```

I tried checking docs and tried searching on google about the error, but didn't found anything helpful.

thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: This would only happen if you are clicking the link in one browser and finishing the process in another browser. The `pkce` auth flow is used in the case in order to prevent someone hijacking your session. Please give some more information on what browser you are using and how you are initiating the flow.

Comment: @AndrewSmith actually the issue was that i was running the site locally, so the intial request goes from localhost to supabase for the auth and whatever happens, but the problem was that in the supabase url config, localhost was not present, so it redirected to the site url, which was set to an vercel deployment of the site, so the whole auth just didn't worked, I later got it working though by fixing the allowed urls for redirection, thanks for your comment, i now got to understand what was the actual problem behind all this.

Comment: @HarshAgrawal I already had the URL whitelisted, however I am still getting this issue. Did you end up saving the URL as the base URL? For example, http://localhost:3000? Or did you have the path as well (/auth/callback)?